# Losing type when function called with extended types

Tags: typescript

I am losing type at some point in the given example and I don't understand why. When I'm calling the function with actual values it works fine but when inheriting a type it doesn't

I tried to force the return type with "as" but it didn't change anything.

See the code below or [playground available here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQEsB2CxwGYEMDGYSAygvLgOZgCSAtpWAGLz3IDeoSSAzgDYCuFAFw8EcdBQA0nJNha4EAGRj5cvAPwjuYidJBduKAF5gRafrQBGWPVzgKUMMxetwkAHyTnevW0kgIIgBEAFZQFEEeSEFQaBF+COiBXvw+UWxIcM5WNkjCKTlwkkiW2a5IAL56FaCgkLCIqBhYeIQkZPZUAGooACZgMMxwrEgc+jwC+dricdW1IHXQ8MhJLQREpORUAMIKYBTwAJ6jMnK8-VmiMxQA3DIo9FRDrNwiAEpg+PC9ADzTuu0tjRHkx5AgAHx3cYANz6A2eCleSA+Xzgv3+s0BnTAPX6gzBkNANQW4CWjS+aG0oiBu0wB3EYG4SAAvCdxvgABa4KCYS5jLhcM4XYKc7m87hBPxcB4MBEIJH8gVceAoCjoNQiRVKgyTYIqtVoNSSmTa2Rg5SqXh68QGo1S7WGEwiACMAAZ3falfZEk4Uj5PQKAsEwvETdrEhhnP6w1wqjGkKKeVgAPrcACO-FwcFMbNNOsEIq5SbgqYzWbAxvGprkwwUFo10XTmezlbzPGMOYATABWV0BuwOX3O-v+CDJULhVt5iPJby+eNxqsCxO85OWfJah266IrlPrqemx05t0e+OC80qBtBddruAwADuaAP2u9jij86XSqD0RDz6VM81TIXQATgANmKfJnQADmA4pSiQZ0AHYoMqANFyVdCBVhPE5QVTDMLADAUAQQ5NTDIUsGCQjEkSRlnxlJ4wQVeN9XVK1czzPgC2iVjDV4P8BSPF13T7M9MkHd8R2-CdQ0-AUAL9D9TUwr8iJI5N8F4GBuDAfgoDIuT83yIJqOIw4NK0nS9IEgwO2E0TDPEn0XSksdg0nEcFLnNCA1M9Sm3LAy2y44y-PMgKWxHISEN7EdXyHVzx1-TykkkhdfLU8yEA5Fwgs47cTMy5NspcGz2ydGKHLbeK0sc6TkrErzUiU7UVNQsNsPhJjNXwokkFwJkKSpbgHG4bAUEZZFPm+P4dExTZsVpfYjkJEl6mWJASKgDYOgYJb6UOYhJhZJAAGswEOGBsE2w5tqu6lFr2ekJu4KFQAAenepBqAAWQAQQAcQAUXmdbGi2nagToWUmJ+bZR0wNBeiZBa9qeo4jsEcEWRkCH7u0Gl0YZbgAG1tgAXRJoIGNBWt5SCcm3tJBpkAhrEGGhxi6cxig4YRwjkfZnYicOyZseZGRzsu67UaoTnaZeOHVsWFmbu2oXgRhumABU+YCAWUd24W6QxyZikYfmkcNqGQTlHmlexk7Zc1rnFe2cEScYRnQbJZBsH4NB8B9NA8jABB9qOeXcL1scDY1iO4FFrGAAoZFUE3E55kRtj0ABKDjswQfg4BDgnHozl6SfT5bM8mcmADoadw-rrexKPYfdqFiRVjb-cD4PQ-DkX27pmPEcF52E6TqQkAt-WrY1kfWHt93wVT9kRazpAc9OMEt8YUB88VIbkGrg7m9ZKgh4zw4l8RZOz9NwRc6hOww+LkPH8T3CSZrZe667j7VWfcg6OBDlfesvAACqcBeBjzjpPTeZtZ6WwnkbF2CsFAr3BGvNOSDuI73GH-LB24D4gCPmnGAlIVi2zBCdK+U874IAfvgmexCEA8xfvca6ycACETcwT13YZA-OhcP6KRuEgT6SAABC2ZcCnSZByLAYAZBiJLkgAABgNHS8p3o024O9AAJGwARdMhEXktBUZMUBeC4EOPXEMmjAEkhPqgWhdN6Fh0YR41gycgi7jgJKHiNo2JBC4SAIaMBeBgHrlpCgyczGsAsXTERkjpEAHV4CKNkOgIgyjsybQ5DAQQHIgA)

[image]

Already tried:

- Removing `as const statisfies ...` and replace by directly typing the `const storageCategories: Record<string, StorageImageFormat>` => Works but I lose too much type safety that way. I need TS to throw an error if I'm trying to access `storageCategories.chapter.imageFormats.entity_thumb`

```js
export interface StorageImageFormat {
  slug: string,
  formatLocal?: string,
  size: number,
  ratio: number | null,
  ext: "jpg" | "png",
  tint: null | { r: number, g: number, b: number },
}

export interface StorageVideoFormat {
  slug: string,
}


export interface StorageCategory {
  folder: string;
  imageFormats: Record<string, StorageImageFormat>;
  videoFormats: Record<string, StorageVideoFormat>;
}

export const storageCategories = {
  chapter: {
    folder: "chapters",
    imageFormats: {
      original: {
        slug: "original",
        formatLocal: "original",
        size: 1000,
        ratio: null,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: null,
      },
      chapter_square: {
        slug: "chapter_square",
        formatLocal: "square",
        size: 250,
        ratio: 1,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: null,
      },
      chapter_bg: {
        slug: "chapter_bg",
        size: 1000,
        formatLocal: "bg_brown",
        ratio: null,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: { r: 196, g: 189, b: 178 },
      },
    },
    videoFormats: {},
  },
  entity: {
    folder: "entities",
    imageFormats: {
      original: {
        slug: "original",
        size: 1000,
        ratio: null,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: null,
      },
      entity_closeup: {
        slug: "entity_closeup",
        size: 100,
        ratio: 1,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: null,
      },
      entity_square: {
        slug: "entity_square",
        size: 150,
        ratio: 1,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: null,
      },
      entity_thumb: {
        slug: "entity_thumb",
        size: 150,
        ratio: null,
        ext: "jpg",
        tint: null,
      },
    },
    videoFormats: {},
  }
} as const satisfies Record<string, StorageCategory>;

export type StorageCategorySlug = keyof typeof storageCategories;

// IMAGE

export type StorageImageFormats<C extends StorageCategorySlug> =
  typeof storageCategories[C]["imageFormats"];

export type StorageImageFormatSlug<C extends StorageCategorySlug> =
  keyof StorageImageFormats<C>;

export type StorageImageFormatT<C extends StorageCategorySlug, F extends StorageImageFormatSlug<C>>  = StorageImageFormats<C>[F];

export function getCategoryImageFormats<C extends StorageCategorySlug>(
  categorySlug: C,
) {
  return storageCategories[categorySlug].imageFormats as StorageImageFormats<C>;
}

export function getCategoryImageFormat<C extends StorageCategorySlug, F extends StorageImageFormatSlug<C>>(
  categorySlug: C,
  formatSlug: F
) {
  const categoryFormats = getCategoryImageFormats(categorySlug);
  return categoryFormats[formatSlug];
}

export function getLocalUrl<C extends StorageCategorySlug, F extends StorageImageFormatSlug<C>>(
  categorySlug: C,
  formatSlug: F
) {
  const imageFormat = getCategoryImageFormat(categorySlug, formatSlug);
 // Error: Property 'formatLocal' does not exist on type 'StorageImageFormats<C>[F]'.
  if (!imageFormat.formatLocal) return null;
  return `assets/images/${imageFormat.formatLocal}_play.jpg`;
}

const imageFormat = getCategoryImageFormat("chapter", "original");
console.log(imageFormat.formatLocal); // Works fine here though
```

Comment: Can't help but notice that that's a *lot* of types to do very little. And even with all those types you need `as` assertions.

Comment: Those are used elsewhere in the code obviously. This is just a subset so people can help :)

Comment: Adding to @RobbyCornelissen's point, you seem to have duplicated some types and I'm not sure of the purpose, e.g. you defined the `StorageImageFormat` at the top and then later with `StorageImageFormats`. Also I think you're inferring a bit too much and there are some unnecessary assertions. e.g. `export type StorageCategorySlug = 'chapter' | 'entity';`, & `export const storageCategories: Record<StorageCategorySlug, StorageCategory> = {`

It's good practise to simplify before fixing if you have the time

Comment: Properly typing `storageCategories` as `export const storageCategories: Record<string, StorageCategory> = { /* ... */ }` fixes it, and lets you get rid of the `as` assertion.

Comment: Thanks. If I do that I lose some of the type safety though. I could type without error

console.log(storageCategories.chapter.imageFormats.entity_thumb);
console.log(storageCategories.chapter.imageFormats.cantypeanythinghere);

so it's not an option

Comment: About types, none are duplicated. They're all useful elsewhere in the app

Comment: Why not just use a `const` assertion then together with the `satisfies` keyword? `export const storageCategories = { /* ... */ } as const satisfies Record<string, StorageCategory>;`

Comment: both of your console logs seem to work fine without error with both solutions

Comment: Nope @pacifica94 the console.logs throw an error with my 1st solution. I just tried. The type safety is way better with "as const satisfies". Can someone just tell me how to solve the issue instead?

Comment: See the console log failing with my type safety: shorturl.at/BHKV1

Comment: I don't understand Robby that's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: see it working here: shorturl.at/aSU14

Comment: You're looking at the wrong example. It's the one I tried based on Robby's advice

Comment: This is my advice dude, seems to work and fits your requirements? If you don't like it that's ok

Comment: It doesn't fit my requirements at all as I told you. Not enough type safety. But nevermind I'll wait for someone who understands the issue. Thanks for your time though

Comment: I think you *might* be able to do a sizable refactor and get things working according to the technique laid out in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but it would be complicated; personally I'd probably just help the compiler out by asserting that the value returned from `getCategoryImageFormat()` will be of the right shape, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp8bXm).  Would you accept an answer based on that, or are you looking for something else?